# How to properly store data in sessions

Tags: php, session

I am using sessions (in php) when users login to my system but when talking to a friend they told me that storing an admin status and the user's username in the session variables may not be the best ideas.

They said that if the admin privilege is taken away for some reason it may remain saved in session variables so they still have admin rights and that if you allow users to change usernames then their old username may be stored in session and so they can't log in as their old username is no longer in the database.

Is there anything wrong with using sessions in this scenario or is there a better way to pass such data between the pages?

Comment: Essentially the session is a cache. Invalidating caches is a classic problem to which there's no magic bullet solution. Yes, the data in the cache (session) and the database may get out of sync. You'll want to ensure that they're re-synced; either periodically, or by invalidating the cache when the data is changed. Or you just don't care about it if it's not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks for the response, It's not a massive deal as it is pretty small scale. I'll have a look into those options